# C - why it's return me NULL value every-time?

Tags: c

This is my source code:

```
size_t  ft_strlen(char const *str)
{
    return ((*str) ? ft_strlen(++str) + 1 : 0);
}

int     ft_memcmp(void const *s1, void const *s2, size_t const n)
{
    size_t i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        if (((char *)s1)[i] != ((char *)s2)[i])
            return (((char *)s1)[i] - ((char *)s2)[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}

char    *ft_strstr(char *s1, char const *s2)
{
    if (!*s1)
        return (NULL);
    return (!ft_memcmp(++s1, s2, ft_strlen(s2)) ? s1 : NULL);
}

int     main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", ft_strstr("Bonjour", "jour"));
    return (0);
}
```

I have a problem with the return value 
In main function, why does it return me not s1, here " jour " ?

Comment: You are implementing strlen recursively?!  Why?

Comment: I suggest debugging it with gdb (debugging -- make breakpoints and monitor variables). You can also manual debug by printing out values in functions.

Comment: William No relations with the post.

Comment: o != j ? what do you mean ?

Comment: `++s1` points to the first `o` in `Bonjour` and `s2` points to the `j` in `jour`. And since `o != j` the function returns `NULL`.

Comment: Side note: `return (((char *)s1)[i] - ((char *)s2)[i]);` should be `return (((unsigned char *)s1)[i] - ((unsigned char *)s2)[i]);`.  `strcmp()` is done as if the characters were `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you call `ft_strstr("Bonjour", "jour");`

ft_strstr calls `ft_memcmp("onjour", "jour")`.

ft_memcmp returns 'o' - 'j', which is not zero, so

`return (!ft_memcmp(++s1, s2, ft_strlen(s2)) ? s1 : NULL);` returns `NULL`

your problem is `ft_strstr` :

I suppose you wanted to do it recursively ? If it is the case, you forgot the recursion

Here's an example of a recursive implementation which should work.

`char    *ft_strstr(char *s1, char const *s2)
{
    if (!*s1)
        return (NULL);
    if (!ft_memcmp(s1, s2, ft_strlen(s2)))
        return (s1);
    return (ft_strstr(s1 + 1, s2));
}`